# One to Many results in a single row (Emails Example)

Tags: sql, pivot

I've basically have the following data across multiple tables:

```
ID  Name    Email
1   Jack    jack@hotmail.com
1   Jack    jack@gmail.com
2   Jill    jill@home.net
2   Jill    jill@mail.com
2   Jill    jill@gmail.com
```

How could I make a simple SQL query to get the following results in one row for each unique ID like the following?

```
            ID  Name    Email1              Email2          Email3
            1   Jack    jack@hotmail.com    jack@gmail.com
            2   Jill    jill@home.net       jill@mail.com   jill@gmail.com
```

Thank you kindly in advance for any help.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: If someone adds a fourth Jill e-mail, do you suddenly want an Email4 column in the result?

Comment: How do you know `jill@home.net` belongs in Email1? Why isn't it in Email3, with `jill@gmail.com` over in Email1?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation with `row_number()` to enumerate the emails:

```
select id, name,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then email end) as email1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then email end) as email2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then email end) as email3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by email) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id, name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually NEED to have additional columns for each email but want one row per ID/Name, you can concatenate using FOR XML PATH. This will take all the emails and add them into the same column. If they have one email, the field will just show the one. If they have 7 emails, it will show all 7 in the one field.

```
SELECT  
    ID, Name,
    Emails = STUFF((SELECT ',' + Email
    FROM [EmailTable] u2
    WHERE u.ID = u2.ID
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1,'')
FROM [EmailTable] u
group by ID, Name
```